# Nonlinear system for origin translation

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

the nonlinear system

$$x'=a+bx+cx^2-x^3$$

by translating the origin, we can eliminate any second-degree terms, such that

$$x'=\mu_1+\mu_2x-x^3$$

how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You set $x=\frac{c}3+y$, then the quadratic terms in the equation for $y$ cancel. This is exactly the same as when you transform a cubic equation into normal form.